# Performance issue of multiple `AND ( true ) AND ( true ) ...`

Tags: postgresql, performance, function, database-performance

There is a PostgreSQL function, used for fetching companies, using different filter options.

This function will be used by API generator.

Some arguments can be presented, some not.

E.g. find companies by cities, find companies by cities and categories etc.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION public.search_companies(
    name character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    "categoryIds" integer[] DEFAULT NULL::integer[], 
    "cityIds" integer[] DEFAULT NULL::integer[],
    departments public.department[] DEFAULT NULL::public.department[],
    "stockTemperatures" public.stock_temperature[] DEFAULT NULL::public.stock_temperature[],
    verified boolean DEFAULT NULL::boolean
) RETURNS SETOF public.company
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE
    AS $$
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (c."id")
          c.*
        FROM
          public.company AS c
        LEFT JOIN
          "companyCities" cC ON c.id = cC."companyId"
        LEFT JOIN
          "companyCategories" cCat ON c.id = cCat."companyId"
        LEFT JOIN
          company_visit cv ON c.id = cv.company_id
        LEFT JOIN
          company_import ci ON c.id = ci.company_id
        WHERE (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."name" is not null THEN
            c.name ILIKE "search_companies"."name"
          ELSE true END
        ) AND (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."cityIds" is not null THEN
            "search_companies"."cityIds" @> array[cC."cityId"]
          ELSE true END
        ) AND (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."categoryIds" is not null THEN
            "search_companies"."categoryIds" @> array[cCat."categoryId"]
          ELSE true END
        ) AND (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."departments" is not null THEN
            "search_companies"."departments" @> array[cCat.department]
          ELSE true END
        ) AND (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."stockTemperatures" is not null THEN
            c."stockTemperatures" && "search_companies"."stockTemperatures"
          ELSE true END
        ) AND (
          CASE WHEN "search_companies"."verified" = true THEN
            -- Созданные вручную и проверенные импортированные
            ci.company_id is null OR ci.verified_at is not null
          ELSE true END -- И созданные вручную и все импортированные
        )
        ORDER BY c."id";
      $$;
```

Execution time of this function is weird.

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM search_companies();
```

```
Subquery Scan on search_companies  (cost=345.96..7377.66 rows=5371 width=1067) (actual time=79.859..17375.578 rows=5371 loops=1)
  ->  Unique  (cost=345.96..7323.95 rows=5371 width=1091) (actual time=79.806..17277.798 rows=5371 loops=1)
        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=345.96..7099.26 rows=89878 width=1091) (actual time=79.783..13638.683 rows=389991 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: (c.id = ccat."companyId")
              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=345.67..4545.96 rows=19457 width=1067) (actual time=79.686..2007.023 rows=40031 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: (c.id = cv.company_id)
                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=345.38..3773.18 rows=7163 width=1067) (actual time=79.555..567.071 rows=7668 loops=1)
                          Merge Cond: (c.id = cc."companyId")
                          ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=345.10..3446.49 rows=5371 width=1067) (actual time=79.350..304.764 rows=5371 loops=1)
                                Merge Cond: (c.id = ci.company_id)
                                ->  Index Scan using companies_pkey on company c  (cost=0.28..3045.54 rows=5371 width=1067) (actual time=0.050..74.726 rows=5371 loops=1)
                                ->  Sort  (cost=344.82..351.94 rows=2847 width=8) (actual time=79.251..103.411 rows=2847 loops=1)
                                      Sort Key: ci.company_id
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 230kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on company_import ci  (cost=0.00..181.47 rows=2847 width=8) (actual time=1.823..41.259 rows=2847 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using "companyCities_pkey" on "companyCities" cc  (cost=0.28..223.73 rows=7163 width=4) (actual time=0.159..72.854 rows=7163 loops=1)
                                Heap Fetches: 0
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..499.49 rows=14589 width=4) (actual time=0.095..636.736 rows=36972 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using company_visit_company_id_user_id_idx on company_visit cv  (cost=0.29..463.02 rows=14589 width=4) (actual time=0.071..150.079 rows=14589 loops=1)
                                Heap Fetches: 300
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..1218.48 rows=24811 width=4) (actual time=0.053..4001.596 rows=389840 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using "companyCategories_pkey" on "companyCategories" ccat  (cost=0.29..1156.45 rows=24811 width=4) (actual time=0.021..238.227 rows=24811 loops=1)
                          Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 10.606 ms
Execution Time: 17423.479 ms
```

When I executing body of this function, without calling it, like so:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c."id")
  c.*
FROM
  public.company AS c
LEFT JOIN
  "companyCities" cC ON c.id = cC."companyId"
LEFT JOIN
  "companyCategories" cCat ON c.id = cCat."companyId"
LEFT JOIN
  company_visit cv ON c.id = cv.company_id
LEFT JOIN
  company_import ci ON c.id = ci.company_id
WHERE (
    ARRAY[1]::integer[] @> array[cC."cityId"]
)
AND (
    ARRAY[4]::integer[] @> array[cCat."categoryId"]
)
AND (
    ci.company_id is null OR ci.verified_at is not null
)
ORDER BY c."id";
```

I get 10x less execution time:

```
Unique  (cost=1030.47..1030.48 rows=1 width=1067) (actual time=538.944..556.677 rows=91 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1030.47..1030.48 rows=1 width=1067) (actual time=538.919..547.133 rows=827 loops=1)
        Sort Key: c.id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1345kB
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=217.91..1030.46 rows=1 width=1067) (actual time=100.225..525.976 rows=827 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=217.63..1029.97 rows=1 width=1067) (actual time=97.696..493.585 rows=91 loops=1)
                    Filter: ('{4}'::integer[] @> ARRAY[ccat."categoryId"])
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1451
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=217.34..1029.38 rows=1 width=1067) (actual time=93.444..447.356 rows=172 loops=1)
                          Filter: ('{1}'::integer[] @> ARRAY[cc."cityId"])
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 4652
                          ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=217.06..1027.38 rows=6 width=1067) (actual time=86.888..239.769 rows=2527 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (c.id = ci.company_id)
                                Filter: ((ci.company_id IS NULL) OR (ci.verified_at IS NOT NULL))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 2844
                                ->  Seq Scan on company c  (cost=0.00..761.71 rows=5371 width=1067) (actual time=1.454..65.320 rows=5371 loops=1)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=181.47..181.47 rows=2847 width=16) (actual time=85.174..85.183 rows=2847 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 144kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on company_import ci  (cost=0.00..181.47 rows=2847 width=16) (actual time=1.185..44.490 rows=2847 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using "companyCities_pkey" on "companyCities" cc  (cost=0.28..0.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.017..0.038 rows=2 loops=2527)
                                Index Cond: ("companyId" = c.id)
                                Heap Fetches: 0
                    ->  Index Only Scan using "companyCategories_pkey" on "companyCategories" ccat  (cost=0.29..0.52 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=0.035..0.133 rows=9 loops=172)
                          Index Cond: ("companyId" = c.id)
                          Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Index Only Scan using company_visit_company_id_user_id_idx on company_visit cv  (cost=0.29..0.44 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=0.045..0.144 rows=9 loops=91)
                    Index Cond: (company_id = c.id)
                    Heap Fetches: 11
Planning Time: 37.329 ms
Execution Time: 558.401 ms
```

When I **imitate** body of this functions:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c."id")
  c.*
FROM
  public.company AS c
LEFT JOIN
  "companyCities" cC ON c.id = cC."companyId"
LEFT JOIN
  "companyCategories" cCat ON c.id = cCat."companyId"
LEFT JOIN
  company_visit cv ON c.id = cv.company_id
LEFT JOIN
  company_import ci ON c.id = ci.company_id
WHERE (
    true
) AND (
    true
) AND (
    true
) AND (
    true
) AND (
    true
)
ORDER BY c."id";
```

I get the same 20 secods execution time:

```
Unique  (cost=345.96..7323.95 rows=5371 width=1067) (actual time=72.521..19548.757 rows=5371 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=345.96..7099.26 rows=89878 width=1067) (actual time=72.499..15459.585 rows=389991 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (c.id = ccat."companyId")
        ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=345.67..4545.96 rows=19457 width=1067) (actual time=72.430..2362.460 rows=40031 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: (c.id = cv.company_id)
              ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=345.38..3773.18 rows=7163 width=1067) (actual time=72.349..690.555 rows=7668 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: (c.id = cc."companyId")
                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=345.10..3446.49 rows=5371 width=1067) (actual time=72.266..362.890 rows=5371 loops=1)
                          Merge Cond: (c.id = ci.company_id)
                          ->  Index Scan using companies_pkey on company c  (cost=0.28..3045.54 rows=5371 width=1067) (actual time=0.011..107.027 rows=5371 loops=1)
                          ->  Sort  (cost=344.82..351.94 rows=2847 width=8) (actual time=72.207..99.885 rows=2847 loops=1)
                                Sort Key: ci.company_id
                                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 230kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on company_import ci  (cost=0.00..181.47 rows=2847 width=8) (actual time=0.766..36.549 rows=2847 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using "companyCities_pkey" on "companyCities" cc  (cost=0.28..223.73 rows=7163 width=4) (actual time=0.047..92.344 rows=7163 loops=1)
                          Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..499.49 rows=14589 width=4) (actual time=0.048..743.700 rows=36972 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using company_visit_company_id_user_id_idx on company_visit cv  (cost=0.29..463.02 rows=14589 width=4) (actual time=0.023..185.471 rows=14589 loops=1)
                          Heap Fetches: 300
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..1218.48 rows=24811 width=4) (actual time=0.038..4508.658 rows=389840 loops=1)
              ->  Index Only Scan using "companyCategories_pkey" on "companyCategories" ccat  (cost=0.29..1156.45 rows=24811 width=4) (actual time=0.018..284.869 rows=24811 loops=1)
                    Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 7.069 ms
Execution Time: 19605.076 ms
```

**Why multiple `AND ( true ) AND ( true ) ...` having performance issue?**

---

### Update 1

I've noticed very different execution time — **first 5 attempts are fast**, 6-th and following – more than a minute.

There is nothing gets written into DB during execution of this functions, no `POLICY FOR SELECT` are declared.

Any ideas, how to explain this?

```
sql> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
     SELECT * FROM search_companies_ordered()
[2019-08-30 15:20:04] 3 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 1 s 311 ms (execution: 1 s 141 ms, fetching: 170 ms)
sql> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
     SELECT * FROM search_companies_ordered()
[2019-08-30 15:21:16] 3 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 843 ms (execution: 819 ms, fetching: 24 ms)
sql> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
     SELECT * FROM search_companies_ordered()
[2019-08-30 15:21:19] 3 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 708 ms (execution: 696 ms, fetching: 12 ms)
sql> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
     SELECT * FROM search_companies_ordered()
[2019-08-30 15:32:31] 3 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 772 ms (execution: 760 ms, fetching: 12 ms)
sql> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
     SELECT * FROM search_companies_ordered()
[2019-08-30 15:32:33] 3 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 679 ms (execution: 669 ms, fetching: 10 ms)
sql> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
     SELECT * FROM search_companies_ordered()
[2019-08-30 15:34:08] 3 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 1 m 31 s 963 ms (execution: 1 m 31 s 862 ms, fetching: 101 ms)
sql> EXPLAIN ANALYZE
     SELECT * FROM search_companies_ordered()
[2019-08-30 15:35:33] 3 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 1 m 24 s 875 ms (execution: 1 m 24 s 860 ms, fetching: 15 ms)
```

### Update 2

I've found, why on the 6th time execution time gets drastically increased.
It was explained by Jeremy Schneider in [PostgreSQL In-Depth Training: Performance Part 1](https://youtu.be/OWL8jqrJKPQ?t=2490)

We have a deal with **Execution plans**.

On the fifth time (it's hardcoded value into ver. 11) — PostgreSQL will make **generic plan** and compare it with generated plans on the previous attempts. If it's cheaper, it switches on it.

> Once it makes that flip, it never goes back.

So, I've got the direction.

Comment: I know, this function is a little bit tricky, but it is the only way, I know, that allows me to implement optional filtering criteria. If You know better way to do it, please, share it.

Comment: The statistics seep pretty off. Does anything change if you `ANALYZE` all involved tables?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe where should I put `ANALYSE`? I've experimented with number of `LEFT JOIN` and for only two joins I've got about `500 ms` execution time.

Comment: Just `ANALYZE table_name;` on the command line. Your update makes it look like a problem with generic plans - are you using prepared statements or PL/pgSQL functions anywhere?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, no, I've got to know about them right now, watching a lecture. Written about it in Update 2.

Comment: As I said - generic plans only come into play if the plan is cached. That is only the case for prepared statements and statements in a PL/pgSQL function.